# Integrating functions with $x^3$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

After learning the integration of various functions with $x^2$ involved, I was given the following integration, as a challenge:
$$\sqrt{1+x^3}$$

I tried various methods - too long to even try and post here. For example, I tried to integrate by parts - by assuming the second function to be $1$, I tried trigonometric substitution, I tried algebraic substitution. However, I always got stuck at some point. What would be the possible approach to integrating such a function?

Comment: No way to avoid Elliptic integrals here, at least if there is no "sensitive" limits of integration

Comment: this is an ugly integral

Comment: @tired A little explanation or maybe a link to explaining what elliptic integrals are?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegral.html

Comment: @tired Aha......... So are we saying that the integration of this function cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: @Gummybears: "are we saying that the integration of this function cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions?" I'm afraid so. But it's good that you tried all that stuff so you can see for yourself how gnarly elliptic integrals are.

Comment: @Gummybears
Yes indeed :/

Comment: @PM2Ring Need to murder the one who presented this problem... Wasted 30 minutes of my life on this.... Or not wasted exactly.

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for more information.

Comment: Pfft! 30 minutes is nothing. As the MathWorld link mentions, elliptic integrals arise in finding the arc length of an ellipse and the period of a pendulum, two fairly important problems in physics. So plenty of mathematicians spent a lot of time trying to solve them. In fact, 1) proving that elliptics can't be solved in terms of the elementary functions, and 2) developing techniques for dealing with them, were important phases in the history of analysis.

Comment: @PM2Ring Hmmm... that's good to hear. Is there any direct way of finding out whether some integral can be expressed in elementary functions or not?

Comment: Apart from searching in tables of integrals? In general, no. You basically have to do what you mention in the question & eventually decide that "this thing is a mess". :)

Comment: According to what I read, the Risch algorithm is the closest we can get to a general algorithm to determine if a function has an elementary anti-derivative, and one step in the algorithm depends on determining if an expression is zero. If some functions are allowed, there is simply no general algorithm for that step. For other sets of functions, it is not known whether there is an algorithm for that step.

Answer (score 2):

For any real number of $x$ ,

When $|x|\leq1$ ,

$\int\sqrt{1+x^3}~dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{3n}}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}dx$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{3n+1}}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)(3n+1)}+C$

When $|x|\geq1$ ,

$\int\sqrt{1+x^3}~dx$

$=\int x^\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{x^3}}~dx$

$=\int x^\frac{3}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)x^{3n}}dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{\frac{3}{2}-3n}}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}dx$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{\frac{5}{2}-3n}}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)\left(\dfrac{5}{2}-3n\right)}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{2^{2n-1}(n!)^2(2n-1)(6n-5)x^{3n-\frac{5}{2}}}+C$