# What is the integral of $\int \sqrt{x^3-1}$ $dx $?

Tags: integration

> $\int \sqrt{x^3-1}$ $dx $

I've been trying to solve the above integral for a long time. I used Integration by Parts but it didn't prove to be of any use and presented me with another difficult integral. Also, I tried substituting $x=\sec^{2/3}u $ to reduce the first expression but I failed to solve it any further. Would someone please help me with this question.

Comment: If [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sqrt(x%5E3+-+1)+dx) is any indication, this integral is very difficult to solve and doesn't have a simple closed form expression. Where did you find this integral?

Comment: It's an elliptic integral.

Comment: My brother's friend had given this.

Comment: Are you sure the integral you typed is correct?

Comment: A related one: [Find the integral $\int \sqrt{x^3+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382929/integrating-functions-with-x3)

Comment: Maple says this here $$2/5\,x\sqrt {{x}^{3}-1}-6/5\,{\frac {-3/2-i/2\sqrt {3}}{\sqrt {{x}^{3}
-1}}\sqrt {{\frac {x-1}{-3/2-i/2\sqrt {3}}}}\sqrt {{\frac {x+1/2-i/2
\sqrt {3}}{3/2-i/2\sqrt {3}}}}\sqrt {{\frac {x+1/2+i/2\sqrt {3}}{3/2+i
/2\sqrt {3}}}}{\it EllipticF} \left( \sqrt {{\frac {x-1}{-3/2-i/2
\sqrt {3}}}},\sqrt {{\frac {3/2+i/2\sqrt {3}}{3/2-i/2\sqrt {3}}}}
 \right) }$$

Comment: @Toby Mak Pretty Sure

Comment: @Dr Sonnhard Graubner Thank you